# Htaccess rewrite rule, two variables precceded by prefix

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basicly I'm trying to rewrite an URL like: `/city.php?cid=mine&page=9`

to  `/city/mine/9`

So I came up with :

```
RewriteRule ^city/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /city.php?cid=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

But sadly that doesn't work. What would be the correct solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The rule looks ok. Do you have `RewriteEngine On` before this?

Comment: I confirm that your rule works as expected. What goes wrong for you?

Comment: Your rule rewrites `/city/mine/9` to `/city.php?...` which is the reverse of what you want to achieve. Isn't it?

Comment: Well I got it to work BUT when page parameter is empty I have to use  `/city/mine/` instead of `/city/mine`(and that kind of rewriting i use across the service, so it just looks bad and stands out) Is there any way aroudn it ? thank you for your help